# Using Advanced RTFEditorKit library

Tags: java, rtf

We would like to use Advanced RTFEditorKit library http://java-sl.com/advanced_rtf_editor_kit.html

but it is not clear to us if this Software is free for commercial use. On the Website it says it is free, but in the jar file in the licence.txt it says that it must be licenced!

@StanislavL: can you please shed some lights on the matter? THX

Comment: The page you linked contains this: "The kit is free to use as is but the source code isn't free."

Comment: Yes, as I said the Webpage says one thing, but licence.txt inside of the rtfkit.jar says something else! as we want to use this in our company we must be sure that it is free or buy a license. I sent an email to @StanislavL some months ago, but he either overlooked my email or I used wrong email adress.